# I simply want to update correctOption key which is an arary of object in nodejs as well as in postman. How to do it?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, postman

**questionRoutes.js**

```
router.route('/:id').get(questionController.getOneQuestion).delete(questionController.deleteQuestion);
router.patch('/:id/:qId',questionController.updateQuestion);
```

**questionController.js**

```
 exports.updateQuestion = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const tour = await
   Questions.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body,{new:true,runValidators:true});
    res.status(200).json({status:'success',data:{tour:tour}}); });
```

[image]

[image]